# updating controller scope from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I have a problem updating a scope variable from a directive. my code looks something like this (simplified):

CONTROLLER

```
function newProjectController($scope) {
    $scope.imageUploaded=false;
}
```

The directive should update the `imageUploaded` variable, which is then used to apply classes using `ng-class` function.

DIRECTIVE

```
.directive('ngThumb', ['$window', 'apiService', function($window, apiService) {
        var helper = {
            support: !!($window.FileReader && $window.CanvasRenderingContext2D),
            isFile: function(item) {
                return angular.isObject(item) && item instanceof $window.File;
            },
            isImage: function(file) {
                var type =  '|' + file.type.slice(file.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
                return '|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
            }
        };

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<canvas/>',
            bindToController: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.imageUploaded=true;

                        });
}
```

This is not happening and I don't know why...

Comment: Can you create a plunkr for this ?

Comment: you do know that ng-if creates it's own scope !

Comment: @FrederikPrijck not a working one in short time but this is the relevant code: https://plnkr.co/edit/J2tiZbc7axpoxCvWqA9Q?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/k88yitoShbdrWY5MvsR5? here's a working one ;)

Comment: As this is clearly working, I guess there's another issue here, I think it has to do with something else then the code you're showing. Maybe the ng-if that Angular_10 is talking about ?

Comment: yeah. it's clearly working in your example. so something else must be wrong in mine then. for me it's not updating the variable even when I print it to screen. so there's a problem somewhere else then in ng-class as well

Comment: If you want we can chat about it, but I got no idea how to start the chat here :P

Comment: Btw it's always a bad idea to asume this is the relevant code while the problem is probably coming from somewhere else. But we can't help you as you asumed the problem is in this part of your code :(

Comment: how does this chat thing work again?! do we need to keep posting till stackoverflow offers it?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123833/discussion-between-frederik-prijck-and-sumi).